# Reference for precise form of Mostowski: “sets correspond to rooted, well-founded, extensional graphs”?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

I’m looking for a reference for a certain precise form of the [Mostowski collapse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma), which I’ve long known as folklore but am having trouble finding in the literature. In lieu of a printed reference, recollections of it being known folklore in particular communities would still be welcome.

The original form, Thm 3 of [Mostowski 1949, *An undecidable arithmetical statement*](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-36-1-143-164), states in modern language: Every well-founded graph has a unique strong homomorphism to some transitive set. (By *graph* I mean set-with-binary-relation; considering a transitive set as a graph, I always mean with $\in$; by *strong homomorphism* of relations, I mean $\{z \mid z < f(x) \} = \{fy \mid y < x\}$.) Modern forms typically add *extensionality*, and allow the graph to be a proper class so long as it is *set-like* (the children of any element form a set), yielding forms like Jech 2003, Thm 6.15(i): Any well-founded, set-like, extensional class graph is uniquely isomorphic to some transitive class.

What I’m interested in is a further strengthening of the set-based version.  Say a graph is *rooted* if its transitive closure has a greatest element (necessarily unique when the graph is well-founded).  Then Mostowski easily implies: For every set $x$, its *canonical picture* $(\mathrm{tc}(\{x\}), {\in})$ is rooted, extensional, and well-founded; and **every rooted, extensional, well-founded graph is uniquely isomorphic to the canonical picture $(\mathrm{tc}(\{x\}), {\in})$ of some set.**

I’m not so concerned about this precise combination of conditions (see below for alternatives): what I’m looking for is statements giving **some precise one-to-one correspondence between sets and certain isomorphism classes of well-founded graphs**, as a theorem in ZF or a similar well-founded set theory. Statements of this form in the non-well-founded setting appear in Peter Aczel’s 1988 book *Non-well-founded sets* (from which I’ve taken the *canonical picture* terminology; he uses *accessible pointed* for what I call *rooted*), and similar ideas appear in earlier work on non-well-founded set theory going (back to about [Boffa 1968](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.19680142103)), so I presume at least researchers in that topic had thought about the well-founded version; but I haven’t found it written down anywhere.

The earliest use I’ve found of these particular conditions *rooted, extensional, well-founded* is in [Hinnion 1975 *Sur la théorie des ensembles de Quine*](http://hdl.handle.net/2013/ULB-DIPOT:oai:dipot.ulb.ac.be:2013/214485), which uses iso classes of such graphs to model ZF inside Quine’s NF.  Other combinations of conditions can also be used — e.g. one can instead axiomatise the *canonical tree picture* of a set (as a rooted, well-founded, sibling-extensional tree), or replace the root with *covering markings* as in [de Jong, Kraus, Nordvall Forsberg, Xu 2023](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.10696).  I’d be interested in results using any of these; what I care about is precise 1-1 correspondences between sets and certain well-founded graphs-up-to-iso.

Comment: What do you mean for the canonical picture of $(\operatorname{tc}\{a\},\in)$?

Comment: @HanulJeon I think $(\mathrm{tc}\{a\},\in)$ *is* the "canonical picture." To the OP, I recall seeing this explicitly as folklore, but of course that's difficult to back up. (I think it was given as an exercise?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, since you've already mentioned several references, and the Mostowski collapse is in all the standard set theory texts---it is a core elementary result taught to undergrads in every set theory class, and it is used all over the subject. For example, Gödel uses an essentially similar idea in the 1938 condensation result showing that CH holds in L, since one takes the collapse of an elementary substructure to prove condensation.

Comment: The proof that every well-order is isomorphic to a von Neumann ordinal also uses exactly the same idea as the Mostowski collapse.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I’m after a source explicitly giving a 1-1 correspondence between arbitrary sets and certain iso classes of graphs, using this “canonical picture” correspondence or something similar, or at least delineating a class of graphs that makes this a 1-1 correspondence. I totally agree, I would see this as just a form of Mostowski collapse — but none of the sources I’ve tried give it in such a form. If you know one that does, that would be perfect.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be an equivalence/iso between ${\bf Set}$ and some appropriate subcategory of ${\bf Graph}$ or something like this? (maybe the subcategory of ${\bf Set}$ consisting of transitive sets, or defining $$tc:{\bf Set}\to{\bf Graph}_{_{rooted,\ extensional,\ well-founded}}$$ $$x\mapsto (tc(\{x\}),\in)$$ as a functor [if this can be done canonically?]) (((we could even try to indirectly show it's an equivalence by proving full/faithfulness and essential surjectivity, or try the adjoint functor theorems with more general codomains, etc.)))

Comment: @AlecRhea: Close, except not quite with the full category $\mathrm{Set}$ (since functions don’t correspond to any kind of graph morphisms), but with the class $V$ of all sets, seen as a discrete category; and then we want to take $\mathrm{Graph}$ as having what I’ve called “strong homomorphisms” as its maps.  The conditions “rooted, well-founded, extensional” then exactly cut it down to a large discrete subcategory, hence allowing it to be equivalent to the discrete category on a class.

Answer (score 9):

To my knowledge the basic idea of the correspondence between sets and graphs/trees of the type(s) specified in the question goes back to the work of Gödel (see Note 1 of his monograph on the consistency of the Continuum Hypothesis).

The aforementioned correspondence was elaborated by Mostowski in the paper *Formal system of analysis based on an infinitistic rule of
proof* (published in the volume Infinitistic Methods, 1961, pp. 141–166); Mostowski used the idea to find a correspondence between the so-called $\beta$-models of second order arithmetic and transitive models of set theory. The same idea can be used to show the bi-interpretability of Second order arithmetic + Choice Scheme with ZFC without the powerset axiom + "every set is countable" (and also the bi-interpretability of Kelley-Morse class theory + Choice Scheme with ZFC without the powerset axiom + "there is a strongly inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ such that every set is of cardinality at most $\kappa$.", this was first worked out by Wiktor Marek in his 1973 doctoral dissertation in Warsaw, see [here](https://eudml.org/doc/268413))

A modern reference for the correspondence between "suitable trees" and hereditarily countable sets is Section VII.3 of Simpson's book *Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic*. For a modern reference for a similar correspondence for arbitrary sets, see Section 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04082.pdf) of Antos and Friedman.

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly quite close (e.g. Simpson’s Lemma VII.3.17), but it’s not exactly the kind of result I was hoping for — the correspondence in Mostowski and Simpson is between hereditarily countable sets and trees in $\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$, so it does more work in the set-to-tree direction, but gives a less general correspondence on the set side.  So I’ll wait before accepting, in hope of finding exactly what I was after.  (Also I think I’m not finding the Gödel reference you mean — I’m looking in the 1940–68 Annals of Math, and Note 1 is about a proj. well-order of the reals.)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for the positive feedback. I have added a reference for the correspondence with arbitrary sets (first worked out in detail by Marek; see also the last sentence of the last paragraph of my answer).  As for the Gödel reference, currently I do not have it as my disposal to check; I relied on Simpson's historical notes to Section VII.3 of his book.